# Trimming a string down

Tags: php

I'm trying to cut a chunk of text down to *around* 30 characters. If it's shorter, I want the previous string. On top of that, it has forum-style code in. I want to strip out everything between square-brackets (`[]`)

I'm using a pair of functions to do that. `forum_extract` is what I call.

```
function forum_extract($text) {
        return str_replace("\n",'<br />', limit_text(preg_replace('/\[[^\]]+\]/', '', $text), 30));
}

function limit_text($text, $limit) {
        if (strlen($text) <= $limit)
                return $text;

        $words = str_word_count($text, 2);
        $pos = array_keys($words);
        return substr($text, 0, $pos[$limit]) . '...';
}
```

The problem comes in `limit_text` when the provided `$text` is shorter than the limit. All I get back is a "...".

For that to happen, it must have passed the guard-clause in `limit_text`. But how?

Here is a literal that gets passed into `limit_text` but comes out as "...":

```
Friend of ours paid 150€ the other day from Malaga. Spread across 4 people it didn't seem to bad, given it was a 8+ hour day for the driver, petrol etc.
```

Comment: Could you provide an example input that triggers the problem?

Comment: That text is definitely not shorter tan 30 Chars :)

Comment: And the answer is definitely not realted to the guard clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is related to your `$pos[$limit]` statement as this will only work if `$limit` is one of the keys contained in `$pos` and `$pos` is actually an 0-based array of the numeric positions of the respective words in your string.

Let's take a look at the example from the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php):

```
$str = "Hello fri3nd, you're
    looking          good today!";
$words = str_word_count($str, 2);
/*
 * Array
 * (
 *     [0] => Hello
 *     [6] => fri
 *     [10] => nd
 *     [14] => you're
 *     [29] => looking
 *     [46] => good
 *     [51] => today
 * )
 */

$pos = array_keys($words);
/*
 * Array
 * (
 *     [0] => 0
 *     [1] => 6
 *     [2] => 10
 *     [3] => 14
 *     [4] => 29
 *     [5] => 46
 *     [6] => 51
 * )
 */
```

Without having tested the following code, I'd try:

```
function limit_text($text, $limit) {
    if (strlen($text) <= $limit) {
            return $text;
    }

    $words = str_word_count($text, 2);
    $cut_pos = strlen($text);
    foreach ($words as $pos => $word) {
        $end = $pos + strlen($word);
        if ($end > $limit) {
            $cut_pos = $end;
            break;
        }
    }
    return substr($text, 0, $cut_pos) . '...';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The last three lines of your limit_text function are incorrect. You probably want to cut off at a word boundary. I would let php do that using [`wordwrap()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php):

```
$text = wordwrap($text, $limit - 3);
# Or a bit faster (depending on your average string size,
# wrapping 20kb of text could take some time):
# $text = wordwrap(substr($text, 0, $limit), $limit - 3);
if ($pos = (strpos($text, "\n"))) {
    $text = substr($text, 0, $pos);
}
return $text . '...';
```